# DotNetNuke 7.0 community edition editor buttons do link to casino and other sites sometimes

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I experience in `DNN 7.0 Community edition` that, while editing the pages, the icons that should lead me to the setting of the module sometimes lead me to a casino or sex site.

Somebody else who experiences this?
Somebody knows how to solve this annoying issue?

Thanks for all comments!

Comment: I have not every experienced that, or heard of that happening...  Are you using a non-standard DNN skin?

Comment: No, I use the standard gravity skin. But maybe it is some adware in my browser. I am underway to check this right now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got something injected on your page that should be. I would start by viewing the HTML source of the page that causes a problem and looking for the code there to see if there are any links that shouldn't be.

If you find that code, try to figure out if it is coming from a module

Comment: Thanks for your response! I wonder if it might be adware in my browser. the Portal has never been online on a server as I am still under construction.

Comment: That is also a possibility